# Correct queryset to get model instances between two date fields

Tags: python, django

Like in the title I want to get all my model instances that are between two date fields (`startdate` and `enddate`).

This is the implementation of my model:

```
class HonorKegiatan(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     jenisKegiatan = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=masterkegiatan)
     honor = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
     keterangan = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
     startdate= models.DateField(null=True)
     enddate= models.DateField(null=True)
```

I want to show the instances of my model where datetime.datetime.now() is between startdate and enddate fields.

How I must compose my queryset?

This is what I've tried so far without any results:

```
honor = HonorKegiatan.objects.filter(
    startdate__gte=datetime.datetime.now(),
    enddate__lte=datetime.datetime.now()
).values_list('honor',flat=True)
```

What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First please double check that you actually have entries in the database and you're using the correct database (not using a dev/staging/production environment which has no entries).

Your filtering code has issue, it should be like this:

```
honor = HonorKegiatan.objects.filter(startdate__lt=datetime.datetime.now(),enddate__gt=datetime.datetime.now()).values_list('honor',flat=True)
```

The startdate needs to be lower than now and enddate greater than now. Only then "now" will be in between.

You used `lte` with enddate and `gte` with startdate which was the issue. It's better not to use equal in both end if you want in between. I updated code to use `gt` and `lt` instead.

With django, it's better to import the `timezone` from `django.utils` and then use `timezone.now()` instead of the built in datetime module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the code `startdate__gte=datetime.datetime.now(),enddate__lte=datetime.datetime.now()`

Here you are trying to compare with a value that is likely not to be present in the modal as it the current time value. also, the code is not well written, you should first set the values of comparing variables and then use in your filters.

a possible correction can be

```
starttime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
starttime = starttime.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
endtime = datetime.datetime.now()
honor = HonorKegiatan.objects.filter(startdate__gte=startdate, enddate__lte=enddate).values_list('honor',flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the queryset you have done!
how can exist something that have startdate greater then datetime.now and enddate minor then datetime.now?
try invert gte and lte!

```
honor = HonorKegiatan.objects.filter(
    startdate__lte=datetime.datetime.now(),
    enddate__gte=datetime.datetime.now()
).values_list('honor',flat=True)
```

Comment: You are saying current time is less that start date? and current time is greater than end date? Are you sure? Invert should help.

Comment: @AnupYadav inverted is the same as the queryset of the OP (that does not work)! that is read as startdate less then current time and endate greater then current time! look at the op queryset!!! is the one you suggest to use (that is wrong)!